# Point to an indexed pointed

Tags: c++, pointers, indexing

I am currently working on writing strstr from scratch.  In my code, I am indexing a string and I eventually need to save a particular point on the string using another pointer.  Here is the section of the code that I am struggling with:

```
char *save_str;
for(int i=0;i<length_str1; i++)
{
    if(str1[i]==str2[0])
    {
        *save_str=str[i];
```

However, it is telling me that I cannot do this.  How can I have a pointer point to a particular character in an index?

Comment: What is the error message given by the compiler?

Comment: You should make very sure you understand the difference between pointers and things-pointers-point-to before you tackle something like this. `*save_str` doesn't make sense in your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Practical Answer**

```
save_str = &str[i];
```

**Extended Descriptive Boring Answer**

There is a feature in "pure c" and "c++" about arrays and pointers.

When a programmer wants **the address** of the full array, or the first item, the "&" operator is not required, even considered as an error or warning by some compilers.

```
char *myptr = NULL;
char myarray[512];

strcpy(myarray, "Hello World");

// this is the same:
myptr = myarray;

// this is the same:
myptr = &myarray[0];
```

When a programmer wants **the address** of a particular item, then the "&" operator is required:

```
save_str = &str[i];
```

I read somewhere, that, these feature was added, in purpouse.

Many developer avoid this, and use pointer arithmetics, instead:

```
...

char *save_str;
...

// "&" not required
char *auxptr = str1;

for(int i=0; i < length_str1; i++)
{
    // compare contents of pointer, not pointer, itself
    if(*auxptr == str2[0])
    {
        *save_str = *auxptr;
    }

    // move pointer to next consecutive location
    auxptr++;
}

...
```

Personally, I wish, "&" should be use always, and avoid confusion.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from these two ways:

```
save_str = &str[i];

or

save_str = str+i;
```